# 302 status code when trying to retrieve token from rest framework

Tags: django, curl, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to retrieve a token via the django rest framework
My api.views.py looks like this

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import parsers
from rest_framework import renderers
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.authtoken.serializers import AuthTokenSerializer


class ObtainAuthToken(APIView):
    throttle_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
    parser_classes = (parsers.FormParser, parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.JSONParser,)
    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer
    model = Token

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=serializer.object['user'])
            return Response({'token': token.key})
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

my url looks like:

```
url(r'^api-token-auth/$', ObtainAuthToken.as_view())
```

When I request the auth token, I don't get a response and I get a 302 status code
I am requesting the token with curl:

```
curl -X POST -d "username=admin&password=pass" http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/
```

Am I getting redirected?  Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is content of that response? It seems unlikely rest framework will return 302.

Comment: I does not return anything, all i get is `myhostname$`  In the terminal it says: `05/Feb/2014 12:47:25] "POST /api-token-auth/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0`

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the value of APPEND_SLASH to see if that is doing it, from djangos docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash

> Default: True
>
> When set to True, if the request URL does not match any of the patterns in the URLconf and it doesn’t end in a slash, an HTTP redirect is issued to the same URL with a slash appended. >Note that the redirect may cause any data submitted in a POST request to be lost.
>
> The APPEND_SLASH setting is only used if CommonMiddleware is installed

The other thing to check is that you are using curl as you expect, try the following command:

```
curl --data "username=xxx&password=xxx" http://localhost:8000/api/token-auth/
```

As an aside from the docs:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#tokenauthentication

We can keep things a little cleaner by adding just the following to your url patterns:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', 'rest_framework.authtoken.views.obtain_auth_token')
)
```

It also says further down that page:

> If you need a customized version of the obtain_auth_token view, you can do so by overriding the ObtainAuthToken view class, and using that in your url conf instead.

You could do that by doing something like this:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken

class ModifiedObtainAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):
    pass

modified_obtain_auth_token = ModifiedObtainAuthToken.as_view()
```

and then adding something like:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', 'yourapp.views.modified_obtain_auth_token')
)
```

Comment: I do like the latter part of this answer, it helped me clean up my code and I gave you an upvote for that.  Unfortunately the APPEND_SLASH setting and the modified curl request didn't return any data.